# Dividing the string with multiple matches in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a string that has to be split for words that are present in "words"

```py
words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
text = " long statement word1 statement1 word2 statement2 word3 statement3 "  # a single lined string
```

The code I'm using, is there any simple way for this?

```
  for l in words:
        if l == "word1": t1 = text.split(l)
        if l == "word2": t2 = str(t1[1]).split(l)
        if l == "word3": t3 = str(t2[1]).split(l)
    
    print(t1[0])
    print(t2[0])
    print(t3[0])
```

The output is like:

```
statement
statement1
statement2
statement3
```

Comment: Your desired output doesn't match the fact that `text` begins with " long ".

Answer (score 3):

How about using [itertools.**groupby**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
text = " long statement word1 statement1 word2 statement2 word3 statement "
delimiters = set(words)
statements = [
    ' '.join(g) for k, g in groupby(text.split(), lambda w: w in delimiters)
    if not k
]
print(statements)
```

**Output:**

```
['long statement', 'statement1', 'statement2', 'statement3']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could Regex for solving your problem in this way.

```
import re

words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
text = " long statement word1 statement1 word2 statement2 word3 statement3 "
    
print(*re.split('|'.join(words),text), sep="\n")
```

Comment: You can avoid the loop by using join - `re.split('|'.join(words), text)`

Comment: @Anurag singh, For this code we need to make `print(*re.split(strs,text), sep="")`  else the code prints every letter in string  in new lines

Comment: I've done that intentionally. As the original posted question had printed splits on new lines